# Qt Installer Framework : Create shortcut on the desktop

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I use Qt Installer framework 1.5

After the installation, I would like to add a shortcut on the desktop.

In my file installscript.qs, I tried :

```
Component.prototype.createOperationsForPath = function()
{
  if (installer.value("os") === "win")
  {
    try {
      component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/App.exe", "@DesktopDir@/App.lnk");
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, the shortcut isn't created and I don't have any error messages.
The documentation on Internet is really light.

Any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Try adding `component.createOperations();` to the first line of the function.

Comment: Does it work when you try to create the shortcut on the Start menu?  Did you add the script to your package XML file?  Did you declare the component (i.e.,  `function Component() { }`)?

Comment: No, nothing in the Start menu (I'm on Windows 8.1, so Modern UI is the start menu) Yes I added the script in the XML file

Answer (score 15):

Try this. It's working for me.

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    try {
        // call the base create operations function
        component.createOperations();
        if (installer.value("os") == "win") { 
            try {
                var userProfile = installer.environmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
                installer.setValue("UserProfile", userProfile);
                component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@\\MiamPlayer.exe", "@UserProfile@\\Desktop\\MiamPlayer.lnk");
            } catch (e) {
                // Do nothing if key doesn't exist
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also know to make it optional, i.e. how to ask user if one is wanted?

Answer (score 13):

I know this answer comes very late, but i hope it can help other users:

(Qt 5.13)

```
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", 
                            "@TargetDir@/App.exe",// target
                            "@DesktopDir@/App.lnk",// link-path
                            "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@",// working-dir
                            "iconPath=@TargetDir@/App.exe", "iconId=0",// icon
                            "description=Start App");// description
```

Comment: Do you also know to make it optional, i.e. how to ask user if one is wanted?

Comment: add a QCheckBox widget (with a name) to the page of the installer and at installation check if the widgets checked property has the value true.

(I just looked up the code of my old project, I do not know if nowadays there is a better way)